# How can I access the /android_asset/ folder on my phone?

Tags: files

or in other words:

1. Where is it?
2. Can I access it without root access?

I've been searching in ASTRO file manager but I can't find it.  What is the full path?

Comment: What is this folder used for?  I've never heard of it before?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's even a physical location or a dynamic one that is app specific, but I'm trying to change the page that is opened when I open a new tab in Dolphin HD.  It points to file:///android_asset/new_tab.htm.  I'd rather it open to my homepage, and since there's no setting to do this I figured I'd edit this file and make it exactly what I want.

Comment: Ah, it sounds like the assets folder of an APK. You may not be able to alter it since APKs are signed by the developer.  See CommonsWare's answer.

Comment: Have you seen this? [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50713071/3233722) Probably a duplicate answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where is it?

It is inside an APK file for some application.

> Can I access it without root access?

You can download the APK to your desktop and unZIP it.

> Dolphin HD...points to file:///android_asset/new_tab.htm

Since Dolphin HD is not open source (AFAIK), you have no way of changing this behavior. You also cannot modify this file unless you sign the resulting modified APK file with your own digital signature, in which case you would never again be able to get an update to Dolphin HD.

You may wish to contact the Dolphin HD developers and suggest a feature that meets your needs.

Comment: Is the app run from the APK or is that just an installer package?

Comment: @matt: It's a bit of both, really. AFAIK, though, assets stay in the APK file and are loaded out of there.

Comment: Ohhh, I think I'm getting in a little over my head.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was actually able to find the file.  I was trying to email myself the APK from ASTRO (long click on file) and it always showed it as attached to my message but it was never there when I received the email.  I was able to get directly to the file when I chose "Add Attachment" in gmail.  It brought me to the APK file and then let me browse inside the file instead of running it.  I emailed myself the new_tab.htm. Unfortunately it doesn't look like I'll be able to get it back in there.  Oh well, emailed the Dolphin HD dev, hope they add the feature.